# I want to create a Y/N flag. If one of the same accounts ends in M then mark as N else Y if all ends with D

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(ACCOUNT,6,1) = 'M' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS POSTING_FLAG
FROM ALL_QUEUES

Desired Output:

Account    Flag

12345D N

12345D N

12345D N

12345M N

22222D Y

22222D Y

22222D Y

22222D Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic function; this uses a CTE to provide your base data with just the account:

```
with all_queues (account) as (
  select '12345D' from dual
  union all select '12345D' from dual
  union all select '12345D' from dual
  union all select '12345M' from dual
  union all select '22222D' from dual
  union all select '22222D' from dual
  union all select '22222D' from dual
  union all select '22222D' from dual
)
select account, 
  case max(substr(account, -1))
      over (partition by substr(account, 1, length(account) - 1))
    when 'M' then 'N' else 'Y' end as posting_flag
from all_queues;

ACCOUNT POSTING_FLAG
------- ------------
12345D  N
12345D  N
12345D  N
12345M  N
22222D  Y
22222D  Y
22222D  Y
22222D  Y

8 rows selected.
```

If the account is really always seven characters then you can simplify the partition substring.